# welcome message duplicated in Facebook channel

Tags: botframework

I'm using the following pattern used in multiple samples and it works fine in WebChat and Emulator channels but when I connected my bot to the Facebook channel it sends a duplicate welcome message.

```
        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var welcomeText = "Hello and welcome!";
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(welcomeText, welcomeText), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked a lot with the OnMembersAdded, so I also still have some missing understanding there, and I haven't worked with facebook bots at all, so this is just a simple guess in case it can help - it might be that facebook is sending multiple users in the membersadded list in this case. Have you tried debugging and seeing what comes through?  I would guess that possibly you don't need to do a "turnContext.SendActivityAsync" in every loop of the foreach - maybe just do a check if you need to send *any* message (i.e into a boolean) and then just send a single one after the loop if the boolean is true.

Comment: Yeah I can definitely add a check like that but I'd like to have a better understanding of what is happening in this method and why it does work in Emulator/WebChat and not in Facebook channel.

Comment: You also mentioned debugging, but I can only debug when the bot runs locally and I use Emulator. I see there are some remote debugging options available, will try to set these up

Comment: Possibly because you only basically have a single party communicating with the bot in those scenarios? This jump to facebook is the maybe the first time you're extending the bot into a multi-party chat environment?

Comment: So, to debug locally, I think you've got two options. First is to -run- the bot locally, but with a proxying tool like ngrok. I don't know about facebook, but with MS Teams, for instance, you can have a bot that's "live" in Teams, with a real https://whatever.ngrok.io address, but that's proxied to your local machine so you can debug. The other option is to run remote debugging in Azure. I'm not sure how your bot is hosted (web app in Azure, Azure function, container, etc.) but depending on which of those remote debugging with visual studio is actually pretty easy to set up.

Comment: well it is not a multi-party conversation, only me and bot, so I guess these two members are added, but for some reason the if condition (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id) returns true for both user and bot

Comment: oh, my bad, I was thinking this was a facebook workplace bot, chatting in a team - is this just 1-1 bot in facebook? Either way, why not do the boolean check I suggested above, to see *if* to send, then only just send one time, outside of that loop - that should cover all scenarios?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like a workaround and not a solution. I set up remote debugging, but now I'm not seeing any welcome messages at all because I've already in the conversation, not sure how to restart it for facebook channel

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a bug in the bot framework.
I was able to workaround it with changed condition:

if (!member.Id.EndsWith(turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id))

The bug is reported here
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/165